# Comparing proportions across three groups, multiple levels

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

I have three groups.  For simplicity's sake, lets say they are "cats", "dogs", and "mice".  I have been asked to compare the **proportions** of each that are "grey", "white", or "brown".

So lets say my data looks like this (raw counts of grey, white, or brown animals per group):

[image]

Would I have to use multiple chi-square analyses -- one to compare the proportion of grey cats to dogs to mice, and so on? Or is there another method to do all at once?

Cheers

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'all at once'. You can do one chi-squared test to find out if colors are distributed among kinds of animals in the same proportions. Then if you want to compare just cats and dogs, you have to do a separate test. If you do several such separate tests you have to protect against 'false discovery' by using some method such as the Bonferroni method. // As it stands, this looks to be a textbook problem. If so, you should add a self-study tag, try to do the test, edit results into you question, and ask for help as needed.

Comment: Clues and questions: In R statistical software, if `MAT` is a 3×3 matrix of the counts you show, then code `chisq.test(MAT)$p.val` returns the P-value `0.003845622`, so the null hypothesis is rejected at the 5% level. Specifically, what is the null hypothesis? What is the practical meaning of rejection? Can you find the nine 'expected' counts' used in the computation? Are they large enough to trust that the P-value is accurate?

Comment: It sounds like you want to test homogeneity of proportions. This turns out to be equivalent to testing whether the nominal factors are independent (dependence means the proportions differ, independence means they're the same), so a chi-squared test should suffice. I believe this is covered already on site.

Comment: Thanks @BruceEt. I have done a chi-square test of homogeneity however, now wanting to do a post-hoc analysis, I find myself at a loss. Is there CURRENTLY a suitable way of conducting a homogeneity post hoc test in R?

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b. That right, I do want to conduct a test of homogeneity of proportions.  However, I want to do a post hoc now. Can you suggest a suitable test/method in R?

Comment: Post hocs should be its own question (that way we help future readers and not just you) -- but search first because it's probably already answered  somewhere on site. I assume your post hocs are for comparing all species pairwise? (Note that you can partition the chi-square into orthogonal contrasts just like with ANOVA if that's what you're after instead)

Comment: @Glenn_b, I have asked elsewhere but decided to ask here as well considering there doesn't appear to be a straightforward answer already elsewhere on site.  I will add suitable answers to my other question if received.  
Yes, I would like to compare the proportions of, say, grey cats to grey dogs, etc.  
As my real data is 3x4 and i am interested in 12 of those pairs, Id rather not do 12 seperate chi squares

Comment: Look at Pearson residuals for the overall chi-sq test. Sum of squares of these residuals is chi-sq statistic. Residuals with absolute values >1.5, especially >2 show cells in which obs and exp counts are in relatively poor agreement. Clue to what post hoc tests may be worthwhile doing. Use Bonferroni's reduced significance levels to avoid false discovery.